# Select box options not getting selected by jquery with ajax response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an update form in which the data is pre-populated by an ajax call. All the data is getting populated well except the select box. Im using jquery to populate data.

**My select code:**

```
<div class="test " id="test">                       
<select id="gender2" name="gender2" class="required">
  <!--  <option value="" selected></option>  -->
        <option value="F">Female</option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'fetchData',
    data: {
        'custId': custID,
    },
    success: function (paxUpdateData) {
        var cust = jQuery.parseJSON(paxUpdateData);
        $("#firstName").val(cust.firstName);
        $("#middleName").val(cust.middleName);
        $("#gender2").val(cust.gender);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alertify.error('Error in retreiving details');
    }
});
```

I have tried these but none worked:

```
$('gender2 option[value='+cust.gender+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#gender2 option[value='+cust.gender+']').prop('selected', true);
$("div.test select").val(cust.gender);
```

**Note:** im getting data from backed as cust.gender=M for male and cust.gender=F for female.

Comment: `$("#gender2").val(cust.gender);` should have worked

Comment: Are you sure `cust.gender` equals `M` or `F` without any whitespace?!

Comment: Try this `$("#gender2").val(cust.gender).trigger('change');`. It  would work.

Comment: What does it print when you `console.log(cust.gender)`?

Comment: M or F based on user @31piy

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#gender2').change(function() {var selectvalue =$('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").val(cust.gender);});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gender2").change(function() {

    //your ajax

});
```

Try this

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `select` box it requires `change()` event,

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'fetchData',
       data: {
         'custId': custID,
       },
       success: function (paxUpdateData) {
          var cust = jQuery.parseJSON(paxUpdateData);
          $("#firstName").val(cust.firstName).trigger('change');
          $("#middleName").val(cust.middleName).trigger('change');
          $("#gender2").val(cust.gender).trigger('change');
      },
      error: function (e) {
         alertify.error('Error in retreiving details');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See This Demo is working , now u can put your ajax function inside `document ready` function , and please check in ajax Response `console.log()` value is same as your select option value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#gender2').val("O");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test " id="test">                       
<select id="gender2" name="gender2" class="required">
        <option value="F">Female</option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="O">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
```